# Instantiate several times a @ViewChild so i can use the HTML again Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, instance, viewchild

I'm trying to call several times the component HTML but without including again the child component in the father component.

I need it to be like this:

```
<father-component>
  <child-component #id>
  <button (click) = "#id.show()">
</father-component>
```

The html in the child component is hidden untill i press the button.

The thing is that i want to show the html of the child component as many times as the button is pressed.

As far as i know, the @ViewChild instantiates the html only one time, so if i try to append that html to another div, it will append the same. I need to know if there's a way to Instantiate a new @ViewChild anytime i call a function.

Comment: ViewChild is just a reference to the DOM element. Maybe you want to use ViewChildren?

Comment: `@ViewChild()` is not related to instantiating HTML, it only provides access to an element, component, or directive in the view. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use an ngFor like this:

```
<father-component>
  <child-component *ngFor="let i of children">
  <button (click) = "increment()">
</father-component>
```

Then have an `increment` method in your component class that increments the number of children. That would allow you to have any number of child components.